# Does anybody know why google chart sparklines were deprecated?

Tags: info-visualisation, charts

This may be asking about old news, but I was curious why [Google deprecated sparklines](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagesparkline?csw=1) in their charts API ("officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012").

Did they come to the conclusion that sparklines were an inappropriate chart option, not providing but hindering information transfer? Or was it simply an engineering decision, that the could be gotten by other means or diminished the programmer's usability of the API? Or some other reason?

Does anybody have any insode or outside information from them (I can't find anything on their pages)

Comment: We can not speculate any better then you on a reason, given what information Google has already supplied. You should contact good for any specifics on why they made a particular decision.

Answer (score 2):

Google deprecated the whole Image Charts API, which allowed for the rendering of sparklines and many other visualizations. It was not specifically aimed at removing sparklines alone. The API was part of a larger group of "old" APIs that were [deprecated at the same time](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html). Based on this context, it seems to be an engineering decision.

Comment: That link says that they changed the deprecation policy, that when things are deprecated, instead of lasting for three years, they will last for one year. It explicitly says that it is not a notice of any particular deprecation of features.

Comment: If you scroll down, there is a section with the heading "Retirement of older APIs" which clearly states "In addition, we are announcing the deprecation of several older APIs and versions. Please visit the documentation for each API for more information about the deprecation period and suggested alternatives". The Image Charts API (which contains the sparklines functionality) is specifically listed there.